# PHP CLI version issue

Tags: zend-framework, php, mediatemple, zend-tool

I am trying to use Zend Tool on my media temple Grid Server account. The problem is that the installed CLI version of PHP is 4.4.8 and Zend Framework needs PHP5. On an account basis its possible to choose PHP 4 or 5 but not so for CLI. Its possible to globally select to use PHP5 by using the extension .php5 but in the case of Zend Tool which is called by a shell script zf.sh i'm not sure what options i have. PHP5 is on the server at /usr/bin/php5 and someone at MT has suggested creating an alias so php=/usr/bin/php5 but i'm not sure that will work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In zf.sh update the PHP_BIN line to:

```
PHP_BIN=/usr/bin/php5
```

Comment: Tried that (which does make a lot of sense) but still the same error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}'" which is basically the "you are using php4" error afaik

Comment: d'oh, i hadn't looked at the script properly and it wasnt reaching the part of the if/else code where i had made the change. working now thanks!